# For different groups, sql query to replace null value with known value from next known value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL table which looks like this:

```
customer   date   number       
---------  ----   ------
A           1      3           
A           2      NULL        
A           3      5           
A           4      NULL        
A           5      6
B           1      NULL
B           2      NULL
B           3      10
```

Per customer, I'm looking to add an extra column number_NEW which replaces the NULL in number (if this is null) with the next known chronologically known number (determined by date):

```
customer   date   number     number_NEW  
---------  ----   ------     ----------
A           1      3         3  
A           2      NULL      5 
A           3      5         5  
A           4      NULL      6
A           5      6         6
B           1      NULL      10
B           2      NULL      10
B           3      10        10
```

How would I go about this in SQL?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of SQL-SERVER are you using?

Comment: Are you actually adding a column to the table? The answers seem to assume you're just looking for a query.

Comment: I have "SQL table" ... "how do I go about this in SQL"; Microsoft do NOT own the term "SQL" they have a product called `SQL Server`. If you use only the term `SQL` when you really mean `SQL Server` someone will get confused at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**APPLY**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SELECT
    *,
    Number_NEW = ISNULL(t.Number, x.Number)
FROM Test t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Number
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        Customer = t.Customer
        AND Date > t.Date
        AND Number IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Date
)x
ORDER BY t.Customer, t.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is not upto the mark .

[date] column is not clear.So to be safe I have use row_number which I think is require.

Also I think your problem is already solved.I have written this script using sql 2012 with dynamic LEAD().

It not only giving correct output but also depict dynamic use of LEAD().

```
Declare @t table(customer varchar(20),[date] int, number int)      
insert into @t values
('A', 1,3  )         
,('A',           2,      NULL)        
,('A',           3,      5    )       
,('A',           4,      NULL  )      
,('A',           5,      6)
,('B',           1,      NULL)
,('B',           2,      NULL)
,('B',           3,      10)
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY [DATE]
            ) RN
    FROM @T
    )
--SELECT * FROM CTE
SELECT *
    ,IIF(number IS NULL, LEAD(number, (
                SELECT TOP 1 RN - A.RN
                FROM CTE
                WHERE customer = a.customer
                    AND RN > a.RN
                    AND number IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY RN
                ), number) OVER (
            ORDER BY customer
                ,[date]
            ), number) number_NEW
FROM CTE A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table T add number_NEW int null;

update T /* substitute table name here -- I realize that SQL Server allows aliases */
set number_NEW = 
    case
        when number is null
        then (
            select min(t2.number) /* do date and number always increase together? */
            from T as t2
            /* substitute full table name here as well */
            where t2.customer = T.customer and t2.date > T."date"
        )
        else number
    end
);

alter table T alter column number_NEW int not null;
```